# port a kernel module from solaris 10 to HP-UX 11.31

Tags: solaris, kernel-module, hp-ux

I want to port a kernel module from solaris 10 to HP-UX 11.31.
There are any relevant guides for me?

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to find sample code that works for each kernel, and see how it uses the kernel functions.  You'll not find many (if any) useful tutorials online for HPUX: a web search shows only *books*.  Both Oracle and HP removed most of the useful information from their websites a few years ago.

Further reading:

- [So You Wanna Write Solaris Device Drivers?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/articles/write-dev-driver-jsp-140901.html)
- [Adding a kernel module to OpenSolaris](https://blogs.oracle.com/eschrock/entry/adding_a_module_to_opensolaris)
- [Developing Dynamically Loadable
  Kernel Modules
  Issue 1.0](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:sbHh-QMr0XkJ:https://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/Drivers/Docs/Refs/dlkm_v1.2.pdf%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)
   (Google cache).